# How to override (decorate) a builtin fish function

Tags: overriding, autoload, fish

I would like to silence the `printf` that is found on line 9 of `/usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_move_last.fish` because I find it annoying.

How can I do that without copying the entire function over?

If I just copy the file to `~/.config/fish/functions/` and comment line 9, I could break things when the original function gets updated in a new release.

I would rather silence the function with something like this:

```
functions -c __fish_move_last __fish_move_last_ORIG

function __fish_move_last
    __fish_move_last_ORIG $argv >/dev/null
end
```

But if I place that snippet in `~/.config/fish/functions/__fish_move_last.fish`, I get this error:

> fish: Could not autoload item '__fish_move_last', it is already being autoloaded. This is a circular dependency in the autoloading scripts, please remove it.

I tried loading the original function explicitly at the beginning of the file, to avoid autoloading, but it did not make the error go away:

```
source /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_move_last.fish

functions -c __fish_move_last __fish_move_last_ORIG

function __fish_move_last
    __fish_move_last_ORIG $argv >/dev/null
end
```

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: In addition to @faho's answer I'll point out that you might want to look at the `cdh` command as an alternative to the `nextd` and `prevd` commands which I find extremely hard to use reliably for the most trivial cases.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do that without copying the entire function over?

You don't.

The solution is, indeed, to copy the entire function.

> I could break things when the original function gets updated in a new release.

Theoretically, that is possible. However, in this particular case, the last changes to it were

- reformatting, in November 2016
- changing "..." to a ellipsis character ("…") in July 2016
- removing trailing spaces in 201**0**

So I think you're safe.

If you're still worried about this, you can also copy this function and all that depend on it (prevd and nextd, I'd assume).

Or you could silence `__fish_move_last`s output in prevd and nextd, or silence *those*.

Any form of overriding arbitrary bits of functions seem like they'd be *more* error-prone, not less.